Manage my banner ad through a single file
<script type="text/javascript">
    atOptions = {
        'key' : '2a9b0eaaedf6495775a86de65a945388',
        'format' : 'iframe',
        'height' : 90,
        'width' : 728,
        'params' : {}
    };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//tamperdepreciate.com/2a9b0eaaedf6495775a86de65a945388/invoke.js"></script>

this is a 728x90 banner adcode, and I have put in 100s of files, sometimes domain of ad gets blocked and I need to change that, in every single file, I want to do it in such a way that I must need to change domain in only a single file and all done
I used chatgpt for solving my problem, but it did not work properly, as I don't have that much knowledge of javascript
